# Last Id mysql_insert_id with an other query

Tags: php, mysql

```
$query = mysql_query(
  "insert into users (id,email,password,firstname,lastname) 
  values ('','$email','$password','$firstname','$lastname')"
) or die(mysql_error());

echo $userid = mysql_insert_id();

$q_query = mysql_query(
  "insert into qualification (q_id) values ('$userid')"
) or die(mysql_error());
```

`echo $userid` shows perfectly but the row is not inserted into the `qualification` table. Why not?

Comment: Does it error? What is the structure of the `qualification` table?

Comment: Are you sure that first query is even working?  You're trying to insert an `id` of `''` into the `users` table; that makes no sense to me.  Edit: obviously it is, or else the `echo` wouldn't show right.  But why it would work I still don't know ( see below);

Comment: Does `or die(mysql_error())` give you a error message?

Comment: @DanFarrell Assuming `auto_increment` for `id`, an empty string `''` or `null` will both just cause it to use the next auto-inc as normal. (personally I prefer to leave it out of the list though)

Comment: Is `q_id` an integer? if so, change `('$userid')` to `($userid)`

Comment: Please, [don't use `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) in new code. They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://us1.php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://us1.php.net/mysqli).

Comment: Don't use `mysql_*` functions. The [`mysql`](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php) extension is deprecated since PHP 5.5 and it will be removed in the future (possibly on the next major version which is PHP 7). Use [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO MySQL`](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) instead.

Comment: @Gil, MySQL will type-cast the string value to an integer, so it is irrelevant.

Comment: Hey guys thanx for greate feed back i use all these option when you suggest me but still is not insert qualification table

Comment: @DanFarrell its working per insert for users table and show my last insert id but same issue useid not insert in qualification table

Comment: At this point, it seems likely that the schema is relevant here.  Can you please edit your question to contain the output of "SHOW CREATE TABLE uesrs; SHOW CREATE TABLE qualification;" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect @Gil has the right answer.  Using the mysql function `last_insert_id()` is a more straightforward approach however:

```
mysql> create temporary table users (id int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, email text, password text, firstname text, lastname text);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into users (id,email,password,firstname,lastname) values ('','dan@site.com', 'password','dan','f');
ERROR 1366 (HY000): Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'id' at row 1
```

This depends on whether you're in strict mode (thanks to comment below )

```
mysql> insert into users (id,email,password,firstname,lastname) values (null,'dan@site.com', 'password','dan','f');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> create table qualification (q_id int unsigned not null);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> insert into qualification( q_id) values (last_insert_id() );
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from users,qualification;
+----+--------------+----------+-----------+----------+------+
| id | email        | password | firstname | lastname | q_id |
+----+--------------+----------+-----------+----------+------+
|  1 | dan@site.com | password | dan       | f        |    1 |
+----+--------------+----------+-----------+----------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: "I don't understand why it's working for you": It depends on strict SQL mode (http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=61375)